# Checking to see if a value entered in Userform Txtbox exists in a col of worksheet in same workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)':

I get this error message (Automation error  The object invoked has disconnected from its clients."

The code is pretty simple (I think). I have a userform (frmFolderNo).  On the userform is a textbox (txtLIMSFNo) where the user enters a Folder number (FolderNo). Then, I use an AfterUpdate to check on whether the FolderNo exists. If not, it executes the QueryLIMS sub.  It worked fine when I just executed that code without checking to see if the FolderNo existed, but when I added the ability to check, my problem appeared.  If it DOES already exist, I just want to set a variable (FolderNumExists) true, inform the user via msgbox and then select the relevant row for editing.  Then the loop should exit.  If the FolderNum does NOT exist, the QueryLIMS sub should execute.  If it DOES exist, the messagebox appears and the row is selected, but then I get this error at the end (when the End Sub line executes). And usually, Excel crashes and restarts or has to be restarted.  What the heck am I missing?  Incidentally, it still works perfectly when the FolderNum does not exist.

```
>Private Sub txtLIMSFNo_AfterUpdate()
    folderNo = txtLIMSFNo.Value
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Current_Samples")
    'Check to see if FolderNo exists in "Current Samples" Tab
    'Determine lastrow on "Current Samples" Tab
    sht.Activate
    LastRow = sht.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Current_Samples").Cells(i, 1).Value = 
        folderNo Then
            'This folder already exists in the spreadsheet.  It will now be 
            selected to facilitate editing
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Current_Samples").Rows(i & ":" & 
                 i).Select
                FolderNumExists = True
                Me.Hide
                MsgBox "This FolderNo exists already.  It is now selected 
                for Editing."
                Exit For
        End If
        Next i
        If FolderNumExists = False Then
            QueryLIMS
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please format your code and remove the ">". That is a little bitt annoying. Consider to replace `Unload frmFolderNo` with `Me.hide`. A good place to learn on Userforms is [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-user-forms-1/). There is also an [explanation](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-user-forms-1/#Cancelling_the_UserForm) for your error. Also do not use `On Error Resume Next` without reason and in this case there is no reason.

Comment: My apologies for the ">".  I thought the instructions said to do that.  I had tried Unload Me, and that was returning the same error.  I will try the Me.hide instead.  As for the On Error Resume Next, I had just inserted that in hopes of getting around this particular error.  The error does not occur until the absolute last line of the code, when the "End Sub" executes.  I'm still reading through the explanation link to see what part applies to my issue.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Me.Hide is not the correct solution anyway, since all that does is hide the userform.  It's still open and the FolderNum originally entered is still there.  I need to actually CLOSE the userform

Comment: Maybe but it's the right way to do because you should not really unload a userform within the class module belonging to the userform, have a read [here](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/). In order to get at the problem you probably need to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) more resp. show more of what you are dcoing. For me the code above is working at least in the test frame I built.